# what are the ranges of $ \ u \ ,v \ $?

Tags: calculus

Let T be the upper half of the torus with parametrization $ \ r(u,v)=\left((2+\cos v) cos u, \ (2+\cos v) \sin u, \ \sin v \right) \ $

what are the ranges of $ \ u \ ,v \ $ ?

Let $ \ f(x,y,z)=y^2z \ $ , then calculate the surface integral over $ \ T \ $.

**Answer:**

The formula is $ \ \iint_S f(x,y,z)dS=\iint_D f(r(u,v)) ||r_u \times r_v|| dA \ $

So to evaluate the surface integral I just need to find the ranges of $ \ u , \ v \ $

Given ,  T is the upper half of the torus.

So I think $ \ 0 \leq u \leq \pi , \ \ 0 \leq v \leq 2 \pi \ $

Is it true range of $ \ u,v \ $ ?

help me with the ranges of $ \ u,v \ $.

Comment: You need to explore the parameterization further to understand it instead of blindly asking for the answer.

Comment: sir I need the ranges of $ \ u , v \ $ in order to integrate over the torus .  But I am not sure. can you help me ?

Comment: Imagine if the $v$ terms didn’t exist. Then the parametrization would trace out a full circle in the $xy$ plane which hints that $v$ controls the longitude, so $0 \leq v \leq 2 \pi$. The upper half of the torus will be given by $0 \leq u \leq \pi$ so it seems you have the right intuition!